# Python - Error querying Solarwinds N-Central via SOAP

Tags: python-3.x, soap

I'm using python 3 to write a script that generates a customer report for Solarwinds N-Central. The script uses SOAP to query N-Central and I'm using zeep for this project. While not new to python I am new to SOAP.

When calling the CustomerList fuction I'm getting the `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'listSOs'`

```
import zeep

wsdl = 'http://' + <server url> + '/dms/services/ServerEI?wsdl'
client = zeep.CachingClient(wsdl=wsdl)

config = {'listSOs': 'true'}

customers = client.service.CustomerList(Username=nc_user, Password=nc_pass, Settings=config)
```

Per the perameters below 'listSOs' is not only a valid keyword, its the only one accepted.

CustomerList

```
public com.nable.nobj.ei.Customer[] CustomerList(String username, String password, com.nable.nobj.ei.T_KeyPair[] settings) throws RemoteException
```

Parameters:

- username - MSP N-central username
- password - Corresponding MSP N-central password
- settings - A list of non default settings stored in a T_KeyPair[]. Below is a list of the acceptable Keys and Values. If not used leave null

  - (Key) listSOs - (Value) "true" or "false". If true only SOs with be shown, if false only customers and sites will be shown. Default value is false.

I've also tried passing the dictionary as part of a list:

```
config = []
key = {'listSOs': 'true'}
config += key

TypeError: Any element received object of type 'str', expected lxml.etree._Element or builtins.dict or zeep.objects.T_KeyPair
```

Omitting the Settings value entirely:

```
customers = client.service.CustomerList(Username=nc_user, Password=nc_pass)

zeep.exceptions.ValidationError: Missing element Settings (CustomerList.Settings)
```

And trying zeep's SkipValue:

```
customers = client.service.CustomerList(Username=nc_user, Password=nc_pass, Settings=zeep.xsd.SkipValue)

zeep.exceptions.Fault: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I'm probably missing something simple but I've been banging my head against the wall off and on this for awhile I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I finally figured it out. Despite zeep stating that it would auto convert a dictionary into the the appropriate type something wasn't passing through correctly. I needed to use the `get_type` method in order to get the data to pass correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my source code from my getAssets.py script. I did it in Python2.7, easily upgradeable though. Hope it helps someone else, N-central's API documentation is really bad lol.

```html
#pip2.7 install zeep
import zeep, sys, csv, copy
from zeep import helpers

api_username = 'your_ncentral_api_user'
api_password='your_ncentral_api_user_pw'

wsdl = 'https://(yourdomain|tenant)/dms2/services2/ServerEI2?wsdl'
client = zeep.CachingClient(wsdl=wsdl)

response = client.service.deviceList(
    username=api_username,
    password=api_password,
    settings=
    {
        'key': 'customerId',
        'value': 1
    }
)

# If you can't tell yet, I code sloppy

devices_list = []
device_dict = {}
dev_inc = 0
max_dict_keys = 0
final_keys = []

for device in response:
    # Iterate through all device nodes
    for device_properties in device.items:
        # Iterate through each device's properties and add it to a dict (keyed array)
        device_dict[device_properties.first]=device_properties.second

    # Dig further into device properties
    device_properties = client.service.devicePropertyList(
        username=api_username,
        password=api_password,
        deviceIDs=device_dict['device.deviceid'],
        reverseOrder=False
    )

    prop_ind = 0 # This is a hacky thing I did to make my CSV writing work
    for device_node in device_properties:
        for prop_tree in device_node.properties:
            for key, value in helpers.serialize_object(prop_tree).items():
                prop_ind+=1
                device_dict["prop" + str(prop_ind) + "_" + str(key)]=str(value)

    # Append the dict to a list (array), giving us a multi dimensional array, you need to do deep copy, as .copy will act like a pointer
    devices_list.append(copy.deepcopy(device_dict))

    # check to see the amount of keys in the last item
    if len(devices_list[-1].keys()) > max_dict_keys:
        max_dict_keys = len(devices_list[-1].keys())
        final_keys = devices_list[-1].keys()

print "Gathered all the datas of N-central devices count: ",len(devices_list)

# Write the data out to a CSV
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = final_keys
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    
    for csv_line in devices_list:
        writer.writerow(csv_line)
```