# Python - TypeError querying Solarwinds N-Central via Zeep SOAP

Tags: python, django, soap, zeep, solarwindslem

I am using zeep for the first time in Python3, to access XML data from N-central Solarwind and trying to get customer information but I am stuck on **Settings** parameter I am getting TypeError got an unexpected keyword argument 'Key' I have tried everything but it is giving me the same error, even tried with get_type() method but still getting same error

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep import xsd

def customer_info(request):
    client = Client('http://server-name/dms/services/ServerEI?wsdl')
    # settings_type=client.get_type('ns0:Customer')
    # value = settings_type(Key='listSOs', Value='true')
    value={
        'Key': 'listSOs',
        'Value': "true",
    }
    response =client.service.Customer_List(Username=USER,Password=PASS,Settings=value)
    response2 =client.service.Device_List(Username=USER,Password=PASS,Settings=xsd.SkipValue)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

This is written in its **Docs**

Parameters:
username - the MSP N-central username.
password - the corresponding MSP N-central password.
settings - A list of non default settings stored in a List of EiKeyValue objects. Below is a list of the acceptable Keys and Values. If not used leave null.
(Key) listSOs - (Value) "true" or "false". If true only SOs with be shown, if false only customers and sites will be shown. Default value is false.

Comment: It's not asking you to provide a dictionary with 'Key' and 'Value' as the keys, it's asking you to provide a dictionary with the keys and values it wants, i.e. `{'listSOs': 'true'}`. Doing it your way there'd not be any means to provide more than one key/value pair. That said, it also doesn't seem to be asking for a dictionary ("List of EiKeyValue objects").

Comment: I already tried {'listSOs','true'} , ['listSOs',True], etc. but it gave me error ->  Any element received object of type 'str', expected lxml.etree._Element or builtins.dict or zeep.objects.T_KeyPair

Comment: See also someone else having the same problem (possibly the comments plus code posted as an answer might help you): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574837/python-error-querying-solarwinds-n-central-via-soap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format was wrong following code worked for me

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep import xsd

def customer_info(request):
    client = Client('http://server-name/dms/services/ServerEI?wsdl')
    value = [
        {
            'Key': 'listSOs',
            'Value': 'false'
        }
    ]
    response =client.service.Customer_List(Username=USER,Password=PASS,Settings=value)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```